# Swift UICollectionView not Setting DataSource & Delegate programmatically

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionview

I am new to Swift Ios programming.
First of all, I apologize Because my English Writing is Bad.
I want set DataSource & Delegate of UICollectionView from another Swift class , But my Swift class functions not calling and my CollectionView not showing anything .
If my DataSource & Delegate set to Self everything works good .
My DataSource class is :
**LivePlayListAdapter.swift**

```
import UIKit

class LivePlayListAdapter:UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {


    let numberOfCol:CGFloat = 2
    let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

    var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"]



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count

    }

    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell


        cell.labelText = items[indexPath.row]



        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        guard let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
            return CGSize()
        }

        let widthAvailbleForAllItems =  (collectionView.frame.width - flowLayout.sectionInset.left - flowLayout.sectionInset.right)

        let widthForOneItem = widthAvailbleForAllItems / numberOfCol - flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing
        return CGSize(width: CGFloat(widthForOneItem), height: CGFloat(widthForOneItem))
    }
}
```

And this is my ViewController class :
**LivePlayController.swift**
    import UIKit

```
class LivePlayController: UIViewController {

    var heyatPlayGridView : UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       self.heyatPlayGridView = createCollectionView()
        self.view.addSubview(self.heyatPlayGridView)
        self.heyatPlayGridView.reloadData()
        self.heyatPlayGridView.reloadInputViews()
    }

 func createCollectionView() -> UICollectionView{

        let collectionView : UICollectionView!
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - 6
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)
        layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width/3, width/3)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 3

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame:  CGRectMake(10, 110, 300, 400), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        let lid = LivePlayListAdapter()
        collectionView.dataSource = lid
        collectionView.delegate = lid
        collectionView.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()


        return collectionView
    }
}
```

And my CustomCell class :
**MyCollectionViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  let pictureSize = 90;
    let marginTop = 20
    var imageUrl: String = "nature_pic_2"
    var labelText : String = "ss"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        var a:CGFloat = CGFloat((frame.width-CGFloat(self.pictureSize))/2)
        if (a<0){
            a=1
        }
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(a,CGFloat(marginTop), CGFloat(self.pictureSize), CGFloat(self.pictureSize)));
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(frame.width-40) , CGFloat(frame.width), CGFloat(30)));
        super.init(frame: frame)


          removeView();
        // set as you want
        let image = UIImage(named: imageUrl);
        imageView.image = image;
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius  = CGFloat(CGFloat(pictureSize)/2.0)
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        imageView.tag = 101
        self.addSubview(imageView);


        label.text = labelText;
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.font = UIFont(name: Fonts.FarsiFont, size: 23)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        //        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.tag = 100
        //        label.sizeToFit()
        self.addSubview(label);

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func removeView() {
        if let viewWithTag = self.viewWithTag(100) {
            print("added")
            viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
        }else{
            print("No!")
        }

        if let viewWithTag = self.viewWithTag(101) {
            print("added")
            viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
        }else{
            print("No!")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `LivePlayController` thats why the `dataSource` and `delegate` are not being set.

**Creating new instance here**

```
 let lid = LivePlayListAdapter()
collectionView.dataSource = lid
collectionView.delegate = lid
```

**Change to**

```
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
```

**Update**

```
struct UICreator{
  static func createCollectionView() -> UICollectionView{

    let collectionView : UICollectionView!
    let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - 6
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width/3, width/3)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 3

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame:  CGRectMake(10, 110, 300, 400), collectionViewLayout: layout)
//    collectionView.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return collectionView
  }
}


class ExampleVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

  var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    myCollectionView = UICreator.createCollectionView()
    myCollectionView.delegate = self
    myCollectionView.dataSource = self

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , My Datasource is not in this ViewController Class . please read my code completely and answer to me .

Comment: Why not create a it within the viewcontroller its being used in ? or create a static func within a struct and use the return value from that? (Answer has been updated)